# inserting data into database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#

Am trying to insert data into a local database from an asp.net page using the code below but i keep getting this error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'"

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Close();
        string inse = "insert into user (username, password, emailadd, fullname, country) values(@username, @password, @emailadd, @fullname, @country) ";
        SqlCommand insertuser = new SqlCommand(inse, con);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",TextBoxFA.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxEA.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailadd", TextBoxRPW.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", TextBoxPW.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        try
        {
            insertuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<b>something really bad happened.....Please try again</b> ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: second line: con.Close() ??? Also, if you get an exception, you will catch it in your CATCH block, but this CATCH block does not close the connection. solution: have a FINALLY block after your CATCH block in which you: "con.Close()", and remove the "con.Close()" from your TRY block since the FINALLY block will always be called.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a typo, but you have 2 `con.Close()` calls, and no `con.Open()`.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations on using a parameterized query!

`user` is a keyword, so wrap it in square brackets, like `[user]`.

Some comments:

1. You should use `using` for connection and command to dispose of unused resources automatically
2. The first `con.Close();` doesn't make sense and can be removed. Instead you need to call `con.Open();`
3. Create a `finally` block where you close the connection. Currently it is not closed when an exception occurs.

That being said, your code then would read:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    string inse = "insert into [user] (username, password, emailadd, fullname, country) values(@username, @password, @emailadd, @fullname, @country)";
    using (SqlCommand insertuser = new SqlCommand(inse, con))
    {
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",TextBoxFA.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxEA.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailadd", TextBoxRPW.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", TextBoxPW.Text);
        insertuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        try
        {
            insertuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<b>something really bad happened.....Please try again</b> ");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) Usually in questions like "How to add data to SQL database from C#" you see some mess of concatenated strings (most probably containing `DateTime` values in the wrong format). I was positively surprised by the fact that the OP's code was "nearly there".

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping the word user in square brackets. I believe user is a reserved keyword.

i.e.

```
string inse = "insert into [user] (username, password, emailadd, fullname, country) values(@username, @password, @emailadd, @fullname, @country) ";
```

You have a couple of other issues in that code, but not putting user in square brackets is what is causing the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), so you just have to wrap it in square brackets to make it explicit that you mean the object named *"User"*:

```
insert into [user]
```